# Reading file size in java

Tags: java, android, file, size

I have an app for android that read a json, that json is heavy for 3G connection so what I want is just download it in the case that it changes, I cannont change the json, so I think the best way to do this is check the filesize,everytime I enter in the app  check if it changed and if the size is different, I download it again,

the problem is how can I check the size of a file that is online?

you think there is a better way to check if it change?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform a `HTTP HEAD` request on that file (URL) and check the `Content-Length` header in the response.

Answer (score 1):

Where is this file located? To a server that you have control on? In case yes maybe you could use [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html) to notify the application that the file has changed and then download it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have byte array of file content you can find out it like this

public static String getFileSizeFromByteArray(long bytes) {
           int unit = 1024;
           //If the size is less then 1 Kb it will return 1 else it will convert it in Mb and return
            if (bytes < unit) return "1";
            else return String.format("%.1f", bytes / Math.pow(unit, 2));
        }

If you do not have byte array of file content you can get byte array form file object.
Parameter bytes is length of bytearray of file content.